# Excel: How to fill a cell with code modified by user inputs?

Tags: excel, if-statement, module, nested, user-input

I have this IF statement:

```
=IF([Year]=2016,IF([Condition]="XClean",72,IF([Condition]="Clean",72,IF([Condition]="Average",72,IF([Condition]="Rough",72,0)))))
```

I have nested this IF statement 55 times in one cell, to fill a range of 11 years (from 2016-2005). I use the formula for multiple assignments. I was wondering if there was a way to create a module, where I can input a cell coordinate to replace [Year], input another cell coordinate to replace the [Condition], and a cell for which I want the formula to populate.

This is where I am stuck at:

```
Sub MaxTerm()
Dim year As Range         '[Year]'
Dim condition As Range    '[Condition]'
Dim origin As Range       'first cell of the column I want to populate'

year = InputBox("what is the coordinate for model year?")
condition = InputBox("what is the coordinate for the condition of the vehicle condition?")
origin = InputBox("what is the origin?")
```

Assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To get a **Range**

```
Sub dural()
   Dim origin As Range
   Set origin = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="click on origin cell", Type:=8)
End Sub
```

Notice we use **Set**.
Notice we can use either the mouse or type an address in the field.

Comment: that helps, but how do I input those values from the user input into the first line of code, and place that code in the origin cell?

Comment: @ChadOchocinqo  based on your *Post* we would have one **Set** for the *origin* range, one **Set** for the *year* range and one **Set** for the  *condition* range.....we would then make the formula using *origin.address*, etc.